# Bootloading : PC to USB to [MSP430 with USB] to I2C to [MSP430 without USB]

Tags: microcontroller, usb, i2c, msp430, bootloader

If I have a pair of MSP430s on a system, one with USB functionality and one without, is there an easy means to program the `MSP430 without USB` via the `MSP430 with USB`, (without compromising the standard capabilities of the `MSP430 with USB`)?

I assume this is not standard behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure, but MSP should support bootloading via I2C. But a standard method of "forwarding" the usb to the I2C is unknown to me - Youll need some custom software i guess